# DataTable is not a function referenced files are loaded properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datatable

I am using jquery datatables in a mvc. i have loaded the script files properly but still datables is not working.

Code in **_layout.cshtml**:

```
  <!--Data table jquery-->
<script src="~/Content/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
<script src="~/Content/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

and code in **index.cshtml** for datatable:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        //jQuery DataTables initialization
        var table = $('#MyTable').DataTable({
            "processing": true, // for show processing bar
            "serverSide": true, // for process on server side
            "orderMulti": false, // for disable multi column order
            "dom": '<"top"ip>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">', // for hide default global search box // little confusion? don't worry I explained in the tutorial website

            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Product/LoadData",
                "type": "POST",
                "datatype": "json"
            },

            "aoColumns": [
              { "mData": "ProductID", "name": "ProductID", "visible": false, "autoWidth": true },
              { "mData": "ProductName", "name": "ProductName", "visible": false, "autoWidth": true },
              { "mData": "Qty", "name": "Qty", "autoWidth": true },
              { "mData": "UnitPrice", "name": "UnitPrice", "visible": true, "autoWidth": true },
              { "mData": "CatagoryID", "name": "CatagoryID", "autoWidth": false },
              { "mData": "catagoryname", "name": "catagoryname", "visible": true, "autoWidth": true }
            ]
        });//End DataTable
        });
```

When i run it gives following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
>   (anonymous function)@ Product:91
>   fire @ jquery-2.2.3.js:3187
>   fireWith @ jquery-2.2.3.js:3317
>   ready @ jquery-2.2.3.js:3536
>   completed @ jquery-2.2.3.js:3552

Comment: I suspect you are initializing your `DataTable` before script is loaded.. i.e. `script` is loaded in `_Layout.cshtml` at the end and initialization is done in `index.cshtml` which is loaded through `RenderBody()`

Comment: What should i do?

Comment: @HunainTariq  Try to add your `DataTable` script files at `index.cshtml` and use `GET` for `Ajax` source instead of `POST` because you are getting data.

Comment: Just add it before `RenderBody()` in `layout.cshtml` or along with `styles`, but this is not the proper way to do it..

Answer (score 0):

you have your datatable.js in your _layout , you could be creating a conflict , set your datatable.js benchmark index at the end along with your declaration of datatable for all the DOM is preloaded when running the $().datatable